# How to get an image with an extension .nv12 from a .jpg image

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, nv12-nv21

I am working with `.jpg` RGB images on a linux system. How do I get `.nv12` images from these?
I know how to convert RGB images into YUV420 images with `ffmpeg`, but I don't know how to get `.nv12` files from RGB images.

Comment: How about `ffmpeg -i input.jpg -pix_fmt nv12 -f rawvideo output.nv12` ?

Comment: Note that NV12 isn't a complete/well-known image format and it doesn't have a width, height or anything in it that would clearly tell any reader what it is, so you'd need to keep a record of the height and width separately, or embedded in the filename.